# URL paths work local but not on server

Tags: linux, apache, laravel, laravel-4, url-rewriting

Most of the URL links (css, images, js files etc) in my project are absolute, but these don't work on my server. 
I've located the project on my server in a subfolder, so it is going to the root.

How can I change this so the url like `/images/background.jpg` is going to `123.12.34.56/projectfolder/images/background.jpg` instead of `123.12.34.56/images/background.jpg`?

I guess it has something to do with Apache config, but I couldn't find it yet...

I'm using Laravel, so maybe there are some `laraways` to fix this.

Comment: `All the URL paths in my project are absolute` - that's your first problem.

Comment: I mean the resource URLs. Like the images, css files etc. Not the links to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the path url from the root.
If you are using PHP you can use getcwd() function and save it in a variable path root and keep all your URL as relative paths not the absolute paths.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

what i usually do is create a sub domain (cdn.example.com) and point it to a directory called assets which is in the same level as the public directory. All my js, images, css are in there.

Then in the app.config add a new key value pair 'cdn' => 'http://cdn.example.com'. When i'm adding css or js files i'm using it like this.

```
<script src="<?php echo Config::get('app.cdn') ?>/js/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why do this? say if i decide to move my assets to a caching server i can easily do so by moving just the cdn.example.com