# Problems with js Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have strange problem with java script libraries, what included in my laravel project. My main-page route is `http://localhost/MySite/public`, my js scripts and JQuery work fine on this page, also everything allright with routes, what look like `http://localhost/MySite/public/level1`. 
But scipts don't work on the level2 or more routes. For example: On such route `http://localhost/MySite/public/section1/section2`  I'am unable to use JQuery and my own scripts.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here my reference to js libraries:

```
    {{HTML::script('js/Myscript.js')}}
    {{HTML::script('js/JQuery.js')}}
```

Also I tried a common way with `<script>` tag - no positive results.

Comment: Check the source of html, whats the url generated for script tags on level2 or so..

Comment: I think we are on the right way, because source looks like this `http://localhost/MySite/public/js/MyScript.js`on all pages. If i use script tag, it looks like `js/MyScript.js`. 

So,  idea is to use   {{HTML::script('js/Myscript.js')}} on all pages?

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work

Comment: If public is in your route/url, something else is wrong! Which version of laravel are you using? where are your js files located? which server are you using? php artisan serve or php's build in one?

Comment: Yes, public is included in my route. 4 version. public/js/MyScript.js - location of Js files. I'am using xamp with Apache 2.4. Without using php artisan serve

Comment: check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220634/url-paths-work-local-but-not-on-server/28230325#28230325

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
{{asset('js/Myscript.js')}}
```

Comment: Still not working.

Also a I tried to make reference  to jquery library, what located in web and still nothing. I can't use JQuery in 2 or more level routes